# Remove all punctuation from php string for friendly seo url

Tags: php, regex, url, seo

So, I've seen a ton of "solutions" on this site, but none of them seem to work fully for me. I would like to strip **all** punctuation from a post name so that the system can dynamically create urls for each post. I found an article by David Walsh that provides a step by step tutorial on how this can be achieved. However, not everything gets stripped. Here is a link to the article (just in case): http://davidwalsh.name/php-seo.

Here's the code I've altered to remove all punctuation:

```
$return = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i'," ", strtolower($post_name)));
```

Here's an example post name: **Testing's, this & more!**

Results when I echo the url: testing-039-s-this-amp-more.php

I'm not sure why it's keeping the html code for the ampersand and the single quote. Any ideas?!?

Comment: How about find: `'/\pP+/u'`, replace `''` ?

Comment: Yep, looks like the entities are being translated. But why the 039? Try a debug print on $post_name before you preg it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the data is run through `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` somewhere. Undo that with `htmlspecialchars_decode()` or `html_entity_decode()` first:

```
$return = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i'," ", strtolower(htmlspecialchars_decode($post_name))));
```

Comment: So close!!!! the url when echoed now looks like this: testing-039-s-this-more.php. It appears that it only removed the amp for the url. :(

Comment: So I'm looking through my code and I found where the post name is surrounded by htmlentities(): `$post_name = htmlentities(($_POST['post_name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');`

Comment: That did it! One more question... For some reason, it's adding a space between the g and the s. Is there a way to fix that? It doesn't appear to happen anywhere else in the url. Here's the updated url after fixing the code: **testing-s-this-more.php**

Comment: Never mind! I plugged in the code used from the article: `$return = trim(ereg_replace(' +', ' ', preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/', '', strtolower($post_name))));` and it works perfect now! Thanks for all your help :D

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
  * prepares a string optimized for SEO
  * @param String $string 
  * @return String $string SEO optimized String
  */
function seofy ($sString = '')
{
    $sString = preg_replace ('/[^\pL\d_]+/u', '-', $sString);
    $sString = trim ($sString, "-");
    $sString = transliterator_transliterate('de-ASCII; Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII;', $sString);
    $sString = iconv ('utf-8', "ascii//TRANSLIT//ignore", $sString);
    $sString = strtolower ($sString);
    $sString = preg_replace ('/[^-a-z0-9_]+/', '', $sString);

    return $sString;
}

// Example
seofy("Testing's, this & more!"); // => testing-s-this-more
```

- see: https://blog.ueffing.net/post/2016/03/14/string-seo-optimieren-creating-seo-friendly-url/