# Post not uploading to database because of friendly seo url

Tags: php, content-management-system

Here's an issue I posted earlier: [Remove all punctuation from php string for friendly seo url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642515/remove-all-punctuation-from-php-string-for-friendly-seo-url).

I was super excited that the issue got resolved, but now, the entire blog post is not uploading to the database. I have a feeling it has to do with changing the code from:

`$post_name = htmlentities(($_POST['post_name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');`

to

`$post_name = html_entity_decode(($_POST['post_name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');`

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the post name has apostrophes (`'`) or speech marks (`"`) then the insert into the database is likely to fail as it will conflict with the INSERT statement. You can try doing something like:

`$post_name = addslashes( html_entity_decode(($_POST['post_name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') );`

However, a better way would be to use the MySQL `mysql_real_escape_string` or `mysqli_real_escape_string` function to escape the string instead of `addslashes`. The function to use will depend on your MySQL code and extension used (MySQL or MySQLi), e.g:

`$post_name = mysql_real_escape_string( html_entity_decode(($_POST['post_name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'), $db );`

Comment: Works for me. Make sure what's being decoded is actually a string and check what data is being posted. Do `$decode = html_entity_decode(($_POST['post_name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');` separately, and pass the result into `mysql_real_escape_string( $decode, $db );`. Do some debugging to see where the problem is.

Comment: When I used the following code, it gave me an error: 

`$post_name = mysql_real_escape_string( html_entity_decode(($_POST['post_name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8'), $db );`

The error was, "mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string."

However, when I used the first piece of code, it worked! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I was wondering, can you tell me the difference between using the first piece of code vs. the last piece of code?

Comment: The last function, `mysql_real_escape_string` guarantees that all the characters that could cause MySQL to break is escaped. The `addslashes` will only escape apostrophes (') and speech marks ("), and may still break your MySQL statement or cause unwanted extra slashes.

Comment: I'd like the use the last function, but as I commented earlier, it kicks back an error. I've tried researching it but I can't seem to find the reason why. Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Edit: So, it looks like I got the function to work properly. But now I have a separate issue occurring and I'm not sure if that function is the cause of it or not... ah! Would the function prevent from posting to particular column? Everything else seems to be posting to the database except the dynamic url.

Comment: It shouldn't prevent anything from posting - all it does is make the data safe to insert into the DB. Echo out the value of `mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['url'] )` to see what it contains. It could be a issue with the form itself.